# Windows 8 wrapped Credential Provider no cursor

Tags: windows-8

We created a Credential Provider based on the Microsoft SampleWrapExisitingCredentialProvider that works great on Windows 7.  Our Credential Provider displays a MessageBox (Yes\No buttons) from the ICredentialProviderCredential::ReportResult function.  On Windows 8 the MessageBox is display, but the cursor is suppressed (no cursor).  Does anyone have an idea how to un-suppress the cursor for a message displayed from the ReportResults function?

Answer (score 0):

set parent window reference handle to `null` in `MessageBox` call. Normally its passed as `GetCurrentWindow()`, If pass `null`, it will be fine.

Comment: If the password you enter is incorrect then yes passing a NULL as the parent windows reference does work and the cursor is visible.  However, if the password you enter is correct then the cursor is not visible.